# Why do I need to add intermediate CA certificates to JVM's cacerts file?

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, java

My company uses its own PKI. The web browser which I use to access to code repository shows a certificate chain as follows:

```
Company Root CA
    Company Issuing CA Intranet Server
        Certificate to the code repository that I want to access
```

However, when I try to access to the repository using Gradle, I get a

```
sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

error.

Gradle uses JVM. I have exported the "Company Root CA" certificate and added it to the certificate store of the JVM with the following command:

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool.exe" -import -alias company_root_cacert -file "C:\path\to\company\root\cacert.cer" -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit
```

However, this did not solve the issue. I additionally exported the "Company Issuing CA Intranet Server" certificate and added it to the certificate store of the JVM with the following command:

```
"%JAVA_HOME%\bin\keytool.exe" -import -alias company_intermediate_cacert -file "C:\path\to\company\intermediate\cacert.cer" -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -storepass changeit
```

This has solved the issue.

My question is, why was the second step necessary? Since the "Company Issuing CA Intranet Server" is signed by "Company Root CA", and since I have "Company Root CA" in the list of certificates trusted by JVM, why did I need to additionally add the "Company Issuing CA Intranet Server" certificate to the certificate store of JVM?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem you describe happens usually if the server only sends its leaf certificate and does not add all the chain certificates needed to build the trust chain to the root CA. Unfortunately this is a common misconfiguration of servers.

Many desktop browser work around this problem if they already know the missing chain certificate from earlier visits or maybe download the missing certificate if the leaf certificate contains a URL for CA issuers in authority information access. But this behavior is usually restricted to desktop browsers and other tools simply fail because they cannot build the trust chain.

Comment: The intermediate certificate was in Windows' certificate store. I have removed the intermediate certificate from Windows' certificate store and the browser was still able to access it. This means that the browser somehow "cached" the intermediate certificate. I have cleared all browser history of Internet Explorer but it was still able to access it. Does clearing the browser history clear any "cached" certificates as well? If yes, then this should mean that the server's configuration is correct right? (that is, the server sends intermediate certificates).

Comment: @Utku: I don't think that clearing the history clears cached certificates. What is really be sent from the server can be seen by doing a packet capture or using `openssl s_client`.

Comment: I ran the command. The output includes the following: `verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate` and `verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate`. I guess that these mean that the server is indeed not sending the chain certificates.

Comment: @Utku: This line does not say much by itself. It can also be that openssl does not know the root CA. A short description (subject and issuer) of the  certificates sent by the server is shown right at the beginning of the output.

Comment: The section that starts with "Certificate chain" right? That section contains only a single certificate, which is the leaf certificate. I guess that this means that the server is sending only the leaf certificate.

Comment: @Utku: in this case this confirms that the server is misconfigured.

Comment: By the way, the weird thing is the following: I am able to reproduce the problem in IE if I remove _both_ the intermediate cacert and the root cacert. However, if I add the root cacert but _not_ add the intermediate cacert, IE is able to connect. If the server is not sending the intermediate cacert, IE should not be able to connect. However, it does. I have used InPrivate browsing while trying these in order to disable SSL cache.

Comment: On the other hand, I can reproduce the problem exactly in Firefox. Since Firefox uses its own certificate store, I have first added the root certificate and still was not able to connect. Only after I have added the intermediate CA's certificate, I was able to connect with Firefox.

Comment: @Utku: it might be that IE works around the problem by Downloading the missing certificate based on the CA issuers information in the AIA part of the certificate (see my response) while Firefox does not. There is a lot of undocumented magic going on in the different TLS stacks and apps and checking with a desktop browser often works while it does not work with other TLS clients.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Is AIA really not supported by all TLS engines? That wouldn't be surprising, but would be ... dissapointing.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth:  doubt that AIA is done by any implementations which just use  OpenSSL, GnuTLS, Botan, PolarSSL or similar "lower" level libraries. Not only would the AIA extension to be automatically extracted during certificate verification but there must be also some HTTP stack somewhere so that the actual request can be made. And, given that these libraries are often used in a non-blocking way this HTTP stack would need to be integrated with the applications event loop etc. I'm not aware of any interface existing in these TLS stacks for this.

Comment: @MikeOunsworth: this problem is actually similar to the (more important) problem of doing OCSP lookups. In this case also HTTP lookups are needed - which of course must be integrated with the handling inside the application, with proxy settings etc.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Yup, that makes a lot of sense. I hadn't really thought through that cert validation is a "roll-your-own" kind of thing in most contexts.

Answer (score 11):

The Oracle JRE can automatically download the intermediate certificate:

> **Support for the Authority Information Access (AIA) Extension**
>
> Support
>   for the caIssuers access method of the Authority Information Access
>   extension is available. It is disabled by default for compatibility
>   and can be enabled by setting the system property
>   `com.sun.security.enableAIAcaIssuers` to the value `true`.
>
> If set to true, Sun's PKIX implementation of `CertPathBuilder` uses the
>   information in a certificate's AIA extension (in addition to
>   `CertStores` that are specified) to find the issuing CA certificate,
>   provided it is a URI of type ldap, http, or ftp.
>
> > **Note:** Depending on your network and firewall setup, it may be necessary to also configure your networking proxy servers as described
> >     in the [networking documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/properties.html).

(Source: [Oracle, "Java PKI Programmer's Guide"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/certpath/CertPathProgGuide.html#AIA).)

Comment: Do you have any idea why it is disabled by default (more specific than "for compatibility" like they say)? It seems odd to have it off by default since it breaks things. To be frank I don't know how commonly this is done, it only seems like it is part of people's internal corporate SSL usually, but at least some APIs seem to use it.

Comment: @CaptainMan I have no idea what kind of incompatibility Sun/Oracle was thinking of.  Also, the default might have changed in more recent versions of the Sun/Oracle/OpenJDK.  Note that (when I looked at this a couple of years ago) default SSL implementations on Windows (like the 'show certificate' dialog) auto-downloaded intermediate certificates using the AIA extension.  So in larger corporations this might be used widely.

Comment: Right, Windows definitely does. We ran into this issue today but I recall seeing it a few years back as well. Back then I recall my Windows laptop's browser didn't have the issue but Java did. (Weirdly enough I never found this property back then, maybe I didn't search using the right terms.)